# XSL:FO Fill fo:block with fo:leader

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I want to fill my block with the `<fo:leader leader-length.minium="1in"/ >` and then fill the rest with an variable text (length).

The problem is if the content of the text needs more space then the actual column has there is a line break with one dot line and one text line.

I use Antenna House and XSLT 2.0.

Sample output now:

```
1: | ................Text Text |
2: |...........................|
   |The Text is to long for the|
```

Correct output

```
|... This is some Text |
|    of the text....   |
```

XSLT code:

```
  <fo:table-cell>
    <fo:block text-align="justify" text-align-last="right">  
      <xsl:if test="page">
        <fo:leader leader-pattern="dots"   leader-length.minimum="1in" leader-length.optimum="4in"  leader-length.maximum="4in"/>
      </xsl:if>   
      <fo:inline ><xsl:apply-templates select="page" mode="normal"/></fo:inline></fo:block>
  </fo:table-cell>
```

I hope this make the correct output clear.

```
|.... 10,15,2010| Five dots minimum 
|______2105,1| (_ blank), output align right)
```

Comment: If i use the  leader-length.optimum attribute it works correctly but not for the line break.

Comment: Does the correct output have a leader both before and after the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line break was happening (AFAICT) because AH Formatter couldn't fit the minimum leader plus the text on one line, then when it was split onto two lines, the leader expanded to your optimum length of 4in.

To solve:

1. Add `axf:text-align-first="justify"` to the `fo:block`.

   `text-align-last` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#text-align-last) applies to the last line-area child of the (last) block-area, even when it's also the first line-area of the (only) block-area. `axf:text-align-first` (https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf63/ahf-ext.html#axf.text-align-first) takes priority over `text-align-last`, so `axf:text-align-first="justify"` justifies the single-line blocks.
2. Remove `leader-length.minimum`, etc.

   An `fo:leader` with default `leader-length` value will now expand to fill the available space.
3. (Optional) Add `axf:leader-expansion="force"` to the `fo:block`.

   `axf:leader-expansion` (https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf63/ahf-ext.html#axf.leader-expansion) does more to force leader expansion.

Example:

```
<fo:block-container width="2in" border="thin solid black">
    <fo:block text-align="justify" text-align-last="right" axf:text-align-first="justify">
        <fo:leader leader-pattern="dots"/>This is text</fo:block>
    <fo:block text-align="justify" text-align-last="right" axf:text-align-first="justify">
        <fo:leader leader-pattern="dots"/>This is some of the text</fo:block>
    <fo:block text-align="justify" text-align-last="right" axf:text-align-first="justify">
        <fo:leader leader-pattern="dots"/>This is some of the text plus a bit more</fo:block>
    <fo:block text-align="justify" text-align-last="right" axf:text-align-first="justify">
        <fo:leader leader-pattern="dots"/>This is some of the text plus a whole lot more</fo:block>
</fo:block-container>
```

[image: Screenshot of sample formatted.]